# Why is MediaWiki BlueSpice logo clipped in BlueSpiceSkin?

Tags: images, mediawiki

I supplied a custom logo to the BlueSpice preference in a MediaWiki installation. The logo I supplied is 150x150 pixels square, however, when shown, it is truncated to a rectangle of size 150x60, clipping the top and bottom of the image equally.

If I switch to the Vector skin, the logo displays correctly, without any truncation.

How can I get the full square logo to display or is only a rectangular logo available in BlueSpiceSkin?

Comment: Yikes, I installed this skin just to see if I could help.. there doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation online at all, very frustrating.

Comment: @mezzo, Thanks for looking, the skin is meant to be used with all the BlueSpice extensions. See http://www.blue-spice.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit "skins/BlueSpiceSkin/resources/screen.layout.less" on line 20, change the height of `#bs-logo` to, say, `120px`

Comment: Had to use `150px` before it had any effect, and then, the logo is complete but it now overlaps the menu of links (e.g. dashboard, extensions, group manager, etc.) Any way to now move that down?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`#bs-logo` is nested in

```
- body.mediawiki
-- bs-wrapper
--- bs-menu-top
---- bs-logo
```

So if you want to increase height in `#bs-logo` you have to increase height in `#bs-menu-top` too.